# How do you use ScriptManagerProxy in a custom ASP.NET control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

Basically, I have created a custom control that uses an UpdatePanel, and as I understand it I need to use a ScriptManagerProxy to make it work ( since there should only be one ScriptManager per page, and is is declared in my .aspx page ).So, how do you use this beastie, is it just a matter of adding:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy3" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

to your control, or is there more to it?
Could anyone please post a link to  a good tutorial/example set? I tried googling for this, but I didn't find anything useful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your control does not require a `ScriptManagerProxy` to work. You would only need a `ScriptManagerProxy` if you needed to add a ServiceReference or ScriptReference in your control. The `ScriptManagerProxy` allows you to do this without having to have knowledge about the page that is going to host your control. When the page is rendered, the properties of the `ScriptManagerProxy` controls are merged with those of the `ScriptManager` control on the host page.