# How to include jQuery in ASP.net page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls

i have an ASP.net `UserControl` that requires the containing page to include a reference to jquery.

In the olden days, i would simply have included a reference to jQuery in the containing page:

```
<HEAD>
   <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
```

But my UserControl's dependency on jQuery is an internal implementation detail, that should not be leaking to the outside. How can my userControl dictate that jQuery be included in the final page?

---

Researching this, i find a lot of confused solutions, calling different functions at different times. i hesitate to mention **any** of them, because people might think that any of them are valid. i am hoping for the **correct** answer, not an answer that works.

Different solutions involve calling:

- [calling `this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude` during `Render`](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Using-jQuery-ASP.NET.aspx)
- [calling `this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` during `Render`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866511/why-do-i-need-registerstartupscript-for-a-simple-jquery-helloworld-in-asp-net)
- [calling `this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` during `Page_Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx)
- [calling `this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` during a button click](http://forums.asp.net/t/1448049.aspx/1)
- [calling `Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl( { Text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"...\"></script>";);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521639/programmatically-adding-javascript-file-to-user-control-in-net)
- [simply including a `<SCRIPT>` element in your `userControl.ascx` file](http://forums.asp.net/t/1366290.aspx/1)
- [calling `RegisterClientScriptBlock` during `OnPreRender`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751653/register-javascript-from-within-a-usercontrol-in-asp-net)

My confusion is centered around:

- when would i want to use `RegisterClientScriptInclude` vs `RegisterStartupScript`?
- when would i want to call it during `Page_Load` vs `Render` vs `PreRender` vs a button click?
- how do i give `RegisterXxxxScriptXxx` the path to `"Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"`?

---

Short version: How do i convert

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="_Default" %><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

for use in a UserControl:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MySuperCoolControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_MySuperCoolControl" %>
```

Comment: If I was made a custom control, I will place a boolean variable that base on it my control automatically register or not the full jQuery library. That way I left the final user to decide how it will like to include the jQuery. My custom control automatic way, or his way.

Comment: You're confused because you're not considering that each solution you've mentioned handles different situations (more or less). For instance, something like a framework include won't take place in a page load (while initiating caching images would, which could rely on the framework).

Comment: I'd say the only three to consider are 1, 5 and 7. The others are either instance or event-based situations, which is not where a framework should be included.

Comment: Also, this might be useful to review: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html I'm not a "`script` tags in the `header` are horrible anti-patterns" nazi, but at a certain scale, it does make sense.

Comment: @Aristos Then you leak the fact that you even *use* jQuery. Will i also add `Boolean` properties for `RegisterYui`? `RegisterDoho`? `RegisterPrototype`?

Comment: Also, you might consider [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) in your overall application. I would consider it a possibly problematic approach to implement a framework only in one part of a project without considering an implementation that takes into account that framework ending up in other parts. Having two difference versions included of jQuery, for instance, can cause problems. Also, checkout [has.js and Require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#hasjs).

Comment: @IanBoyd You can not hide that you use jQuery, its easy for anyone to see that. Also if you include jQuery and the user also include jQuery then you may have issues with doublications. If you make this custom control for other people, you need to give them the option to include or not this library by their ways.

Comment: the register of the script on page_load is a fine solution and can avoid doublication of loading the same script. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx

Comment: you can run but can't hide. users just need to launch fire bug or developer's tool to debug. then everything is out in the open.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am very interested if there is one... What have you found?

Comment: @Joze I just forced any page hosting the UserControl to include `jQuery` themselves. I'm sure WebForms has a very nice intended way to handle this; i just couldn't be bothered to try to guess what it was.

Answer (score 3):

You can use google hosted jquery as follows:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ScriptManagerProxy` on the UserControl and a `ScriptManager` on the parent or master page.

See [How Do You Use ScriptManagerProxy In a custom ASP.NET Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675728/how-do-you-use-scriptmanagerproxy-in-a-custom-asp-net-control)

This would take care of "Giving RegisterXxxxScriptXxx the path to "Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" and remove the need to worry about it during the Page_Load/Page_PreRender events.

As for "When would i want to use RegisterClientScriptInclude vs RegisterStartupScript?"

`RegisterClientScriptInclude` registers an external JS file to be included in the page. `RegisterStartupScript` includes a block of inline executable script in the page, which is not in an external file.

Answer (score 1):

**[this is only relevant if your user control is to be used in-house.  If it's for distribution then it won't be of much help]**

Take a look at this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196727/Managing-Your-JavaScript-Library-in-ASP-NET

The article suggests creating methods to generate references to javascript libraries such as jQuery, so that if you want to use it in a page you simply call JavascriptLoader.IncludeJQuery() [or whatever you have called your method].

Now what I have done is to take it a step further by creating those methods in an assembly that I have placed in the GAC so that it is available to all my .net web applications.  Now, wherever I want to use jQuery, that method is already available.  The best thing being that if I call the method in a user control, and call it again in another user control, and again on the page, it still only registers the library once.  If I decide to upgrade to a newer version of jQuery, I just change my dll, and it's changed everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If your control is referenced from a separate project, you can embed the javascript in the other assembly. See this old but good example by Scott Mitchell:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131200/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/080906-1.aspx